# For a website: How do I make an image follow the mouse pointer only in a certain area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, mouseevent

I'm very new to web design and javascript, so bear with me please.

I would like an image appear next to the mouse pointer but only while it is moving through a certain area of my website.

So far I have learned how to make the image follow the mouse pointer in general using this method:

```
//(html)
<img id="image" src="image.jpg"/>

//(css)
#image{
position:absolute;
} 

//(js)
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    $("#image").css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
});
```

Can anyone explain to me how I would be able to restrict this to a certain area of the website and also hide the image while the mouse pointer is outside this are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var
    hoverBox   = $('.box-selector'),
    hoverImage = $('#image');

hoverBox.mousemove(function(e) {
    hoverImage.css({
        left: e.pageX,
        top:  e.pageY
    });
}).mouseout(function() {
    hoverImage.css({
        left: -10000,
        top:  -10000
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this? [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eldien/39mfuavj/)

So how about using this HTML structure. The chaser is the div where you will put your image, and the container delimits the area where you follow the mouse.

```
  <div class="container">
     <div class="chaser"></div>
  </div>
```

And consider this css. Where you can move and change the size of the container.

```
div.container {
  margin: 50px 20px;
  height : 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: gray;
}

div.container > div.chaser{
   height : 5px;
    width: 5px; 
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: white;
}
```

You would need to get the pageX and PageY as @Deep has stated. If you are planning on moving the container, then you should also take into account the position of your div.container. When you finally have your position relative to the container, then you update the position of the chaser.

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.container')
    .on('mouseenter', followMe)
    .on('mouseleave', hideChaser);

  });

  function followMe(){
        $(this).on('mousemove', function(e){
            var chaser = $('div.chaser') ; 
            var container = $(this);
            var position = container.position();
            var xpos, ypos;            
               console.log("Client("+e.clientX+","+e.clientY+"),Page("+e.pageX+","+e.pageY+")"); 
           xpos = e.pageX - position.left; //get relativePos
           ypos = e.pageY - position.top; //get relativePos
           chaser.css({
            display: 'block',
            position: 'absolute',
            left: xpos,
            top: ypos
           });  
      })
  }

  function hideChaser(){
    $('div.chaser').css({
      display: 'none'
    }); 
  }

})(jQuery)
```

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.container').on('mouseenter', followMe)
      .on('mouseleave', hideChaser);

  });

  function followMe() {
    $(this).on('mousemove', function(e) {
      var chaser = $('div.chaser');
      var container = $(this);
      var position = container.position();
      var xpos, ypos;

      console.log("Client(" + e.clientX + "," + e.clientY + "),Page(" + e.pageX + "," + e.pageY + ")");
      xpos = e.pageX - position.left;
      ypos = e.pageY - position.top;
      chaser.css({
        display: 'block',
        position: 'absolute',
        left: xpos,
        top: ypos
      });
    })
  }

  function hideChaser() {
    $('div.chaser').css({
      display: 'none'
    });
  }

})(jQuery)
```

```css
div.container {
  margin: 50px 20px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: gray;
}
div.container > div.chaser {
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="chaser">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Omar. This is exactly how I would like it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have a check inside of the `mousemove` event?

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    if (e.pageX > MINX && e.pageX < MAXX && e.pageY > MINY && e.pageY < MAXY) {
        $("#image").css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
    }
});
```